# Compiler In Java

Tags: java

I got the project to prepare a **COMPILER IN JAVA** as my major project for university.
Please help me out with the source code or get me the link where i can get that.

Comment: Compiler of what? What have you thought on it so far?

Comment: I think you've mis-read the requirements. It's your project not ours. Didn't it occur to your that *your* university project would involve some research and some *actual learning*?

Comment: If you told us what language you are supposed to write a compiler **for**, that would still be a very vague question.

Comment: http://jikes.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Congratulations.  This is the first of many underspecified projects you will encounter in your professional career.

Comment: I have written a remarkable compiler in Java for every conceivable language. Alas, the question is closed and this comment is too narrow to contain it.

Comment: It's funny to see nobody down-voting this question :). Every single rep matters ha!

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend the book [Modern Compiler Implementation in Java](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/) by Andrew W. Appel.

Comment: A good answer to a bad question!

Answer (score 1):

In unix, type `less javac` - that also has the extra step of being compiled for you, just to save any issues or errors in getting that working.

Comment: That's a java compiler, not a compiler in Java :)

Comment: @extraneon: actually `javac` is both (at least the one in the Sun JDK) and the OpenJDK). It is implemented in pure Java. The only non-java code is the `javac` executable that is a small native wrapper that starts the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1996/jw-12-jack.html). It will give you the basics. Or perhaps [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/).